# Swift: Turning a String into UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>

Tags: c, swift, xcode

I have a C function mapped to Swift defined as

```
predictX010(inputString: UnsafePointer<emxArray_char_T>!, ypred: UnsafeMutablePointer<emxArray_real_T>!)
```

I want to input a string in the inputString, but in order to do that I have to play around with emxArray_char_T which is

```
emxArray_char_T.init(data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!, size: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!, allocatedSize: Int32, numDimensions: Int32, canFreeData: boolean_T)
```

My string will consist of  let x = ":1580222503,GCP001,007,Male,30,Left,1,IL8 and IL10,0000; 0,281411,-78,521074,-3,344657,132,347776,-93,25,44" and I just cannot figure out how to input it in data of the emxArray_char_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should write a wrapper function in your bridging header that accepts char pointers then cast/create the `emxArray_char_T` in c IE:

```
// casting the func as void because you didn't specify

void predictWrapper(const char *aChar, char *bChar) {
    // do your casting and call original func predictX010(...)
}
```

Then in swift (This isn't going to be pretty)

```
var arg: String = "some arg"
var arg2: String = "another arg"

// use closure to prevent dangling pointer
arg.withCString{ body in // body is UnsafePointer<Int8>
    arg2.withCString{ body2 in // we'll cast this to UnsafeMutablePointer
        var arg2Mutable = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: body2)
        //call your wrapper
        predictWrapper(body, arg2Mutable)
        
    }
}
```

You may be able to use the original types and function, but i've always found it easier (less banging my head on the desk) to use the most standard c types you can in swift and casting to custom/complex types in c

Comment: Thank you so much for answering John! I have one small question, what do you mean by "// do your casting and call original func"? I understand the calling the original function part, it's just bit that I am not understanding.

Comment: NP. I meant casting the `char` pointer arguments to the type needed by the original function. `emxArray_char_T *arg1 = (emxArray_char_T *)aChar;` (on my phone so can't execute this code and typing syntax isn't that easy)